# Blank white screen when launching web app from home screen on iphone and ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, ios7, iphone-web-app

I have a web app that works fine on safari. After I add it to home screen on an ipad/iphone, there is an inconsistent issue wherein the app when launched in web-clip mode, displays a blank white screen.

I tried debugging using the web console using Mac, but did not see any console errors or network activity happening. My initial guess was that it was the file loading time but the network tab would show this activity in such a case.

Could not trace any pattern for this since it is inconsistent, but noticed this first time on an iphone after I left it idle for sometime. Clearing the cache and running the app all over again did not help.

Have seen this in ios 7.0.x as well as 7.1.x devices. Read a few articles saying that the web clip mode on ios 7 was buggy but haven't really got any pointers to the above mentioned issue.

I am planning to put in alerts to check if any execution is happening.

Can someone help with any pointers to the issue/solution?

**Adding code as requested**
Adding the index.html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>XYZ</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!--  to avoid caching especially in webclip -->
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"  />
<!--        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">-->

        <!-- Bookmark Icons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="css/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Health eCircle Patient">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="css/images/favicons/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="css/images/favicons/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="css/images/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="css/images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="css/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="css/images/favicons/startup.png">

        <meta name="application-name" content="Health eCircle Patient">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <!-- Bookmark Icons:end -->

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<!--        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/icons/health-ecircle-app-icon-tablet-ipad.png">-->

        <!--        CSS section start-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/libs/lib-all.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dist/knugget.min.css" /> 
        <!--        CSS  section End-->

        <!--       JS  section  start -->
        <script src="js/libs/lib-all.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="js/dist/knugget.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <!--        JS section  end -->

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adding the app launch code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function initialize() {
        //router = new AppRouter();
        //Backbone.history.start();
        Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.templates; //for using one template inside the other.
        HandlebarsHelper.registerCustomHelpers();
        $.klplot.init();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            timeout: 40000 //15 seconds default time out.
        });

        var masterView = new MasterView();
    }
    initialize();
});
```

In masterview.js:

```
initialize: function() {
    var contentbox = Handlebars.templates.contentbox();
    $("body").append(contentbox);
    this.$el = $(this.id);
    this.currentView = new LoginView({
     containerId:this.tagIds.contentBox,
     viewId:this.viewIds.login});
    this.backButtonStack.push("#");
    this.bindEvents();
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could share some code?

Comment: @Jack Pattishall Jr. Edited to add code

Comment: I can reproduce this on iOS-12.1.1. Unfortunately, there doesn’t seem to be a way as a developer to prevent it from happening. However, I found a workaround that users can be advised to use: simply lock your screen and unlock it. It seems that when the device is showing a white screen, the app actually is loaded but it just isn’t rendering properly. Or something ridiculous like that.

Comment: When stuck in a white screen, I can tap on the screen and see it draw the boxes as if I had tapped on an `<input/>` or tap and hold and see the selected text context menu show up. However, the boxes for tapping on an `<input/>` seem to render on the wrong part of the screen. Zooming out doesn’t seem to do anything. I’m pretty sure this is an iOS bug that has managed to stay around for a long time.

Comment: If I select text when the screen is white and then lock and unlock my screen, the selection moves when the app renders property but the same text is still selected. How ridik.